# Catchable fatal error when extending PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, phar

First of all my devlopment computer has no internet access, so I can't install PHPUnit from PEAR or Composer, then I just download the .PHAR archive.

Then I've wrote a class with PHPUnit class inheritance:

```
require_once './TU/PHPUnit/phpunit.phar';
class A_TEST extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite {

    public static function myRunFunction(){}

}
```

And when I call my object `$t = new A_TEST();`, I get the following error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
Notice: Undefined index: argv in phar://C:/Program Files/myPath/TU/PHPUnit/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php on line 132

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::run() must be an array, null given, called in phar://C:/Program Files/myPath/TU/PHPUnit/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php on line 132
and defined in phar://C:/Program Files/myPath/TU/PHPUnit/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php on line 139
```

Is there anymore configuration to do to make it working?

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit is meant to be run from the command line.

The error message indicates that you are not using the PHPUnit "executable" the way it was designed to.
(Missing `argv` entry, which should be passed down from the command line environment)

To run a test using the default configuration `php -f path/to/phpunit.phar path/to/tests` should be sufficient.

Configuration can be done using [command line options](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions) or a [configuration file](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html).

Please note that phpunit has it's own naming scheme. (tests methods prefixed with `test`, test calls suffixed with `Test`).

Anyway, you usually don't need to create instances of your tests yourself. PHPUnit does the footwork.

Your example is also not the common way to use `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite`. You usually pass the test or a reference to a test class as constructor parameter, if you want to handle that yourself. I would recommend to use the configuration file to create your suits, as it is much easier to manage the xml-configuration and doesn't require any additional code that my result in errors, untested code or at least unnecessary boilerplate)

```
$suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite;
$suite->addTest(new MyTest('testEpicStuff'));
```

or

```
$suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite(
    new ReflectionClass('MyTest') // run all tests in the class
);
```

Comment: How about if I don't want to run PHPUnit from commandline, but I want to launch it from another PHP script for instance?

Comment: Use `system`, `exec`, or someting simliar to still use the cmd interface. I don't know about any straightforward way to call it without going to cli-level. Or have a look at `PHPUnit_TextUI_*` and `PHPUnit_Runner_*` classes. Using the cli is easier and better documented anyway.